# passlib ModuleNotFound Error but I HAVE installed passlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, sha, passlib

I am trying to use:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha512
```

I have installed passlib - I even uninstalled then reinstalled it.

When I run my program the error I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'
```

I am so confused.... I have the module installed?

```
pip3 install passlib
python3 -m pip install passlib
```

I tried this and the terminal just says they are already installed. I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: just press run, im coding it in VSC. It's just one Python file and that's it

Comment: Well, how do you know that the Python that VSC uses is the same one where you installed the library?